# ggplot median and percentile

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to replicate this image.
I was able to plot a scatter plot and the median (but it's not continuous).
I failed to plot the percentiles.
The median varies according to different spell length.

```
ggplot(df,aes(x=Spell.Length,y=Growth.Rate)) +
geom_point() +
stat_summary(fun = median, fun.min = median, fun.max = median,
                 geom = "crossbar", width = 0.5,colour="red")
```

## What I'm trying to do

[image: What I'm trying to do]

## What I got so far

[image: What I got so far]

Comment: Please add some data in easibly readable format (ideally code) to turn your code into a reproducible example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: geom_point() plots points, you want geom_line().  You also need some kind of grouping that separates the lines from one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use dplyr::summarize to create a data frame of the values of percentiles also `group_by(Spell.Length)`, then plot those using `geom_line()`.  Then the horizontal lines with geom_hline().

```
df %>% group_by(Spell.Length) %>% 
       summarize(median = quantile(Growth.Rate, p = .5), q1 = quantile(Growth.Rate, p = .25)) %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = Spell.Length, y = median) +
    geom_line()  +
    geom_line(aes(x = Spell.Length, y = q1)) +
    geom_hline(yintercept = 3)
```

would be the basic idea.

Answer (score 0):

geom_line() for each specific line style/group

Red lines geom_hline()